# C# and ASP assigning stylesheets to whole site based on entry page

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net

Task is to write enter page that allows user to pick state specific page layout in CSS.

Currently I have enter.aspx.cs code set as:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class enter : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void EnterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
    link.Href = CSSDropDownList.Text;
    Label1.Text = CSSDropDownList.Text;
    link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
    link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
}

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
    link.Href = CSSDropDownList.Text;
    link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
    link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);

}

}
```

and enter.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="enter.aspx.cs" Inherits="enter" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Welcome</title>
  </head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

<div class="className">
    <p style="text-align: center">Choose your location: <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="CSSDropDownList" runat="server" 
            CssClass="btn" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem Value="Styles/Site-ar.css">Arkansas</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Styles/Site-ok.css">Oklahoma</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="EnterButton" runat="server" Text="Enter" 
            onclick="EnterButton_Click"  CssClass="btn" />
    </p>
    <p style="text-align: center">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </p>
</div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So far I can get the style sheet changed to current page using this method but what I am looking for is to change style sheet for all pages on the site using the selection that user makes at the entry page. What code should I use to accomplish this?  If it is easier to use different master pages this can too work. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Use a MasterPAge and put your css in that.

Comment: why not just set a session var based on what they choose and then you can just use that in your link to the style sheet - eg `<link src="<% Session['Blah'] %>.css" ...`

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for. However, I am a complete noob, the <% %> does not seem to work in my code. I am using VS 2010, .net and C#